How do I highlight SQL inside strings?
I'm looking for a solution to highlight syntax inside strings of another language.
For example, I need to have all strings in knex.raw("…") statements to be interpreted as SQL.
How do I configure Vim to do this?

Can you [edit] and give some more details on what you're trying to accomplish? Ideally share a short sample file and how you expect it to be highlighted. Also, what language are you asking about? There's no such thing as an AST in Vim. Also note that requests for plugins are off-topic. However, answers may suggest plugins or show a pure-Vim solution if any exists.

I took a stab at scoping the question and a filetype tag (based on knex). Please [edit] if I’ve guessed incorrectly

Does "How to syntax-highlight part of a file in a foreign language?" answer your question? I would combine those approaches with knex.raw(" as one of the delimiters; knowing when to stop at ") might be harder though.

The initial question was unclear and while the edits did a lot to improve it, we're essentially only guessing. I'm voting to close as "needs details or clarity".

just my 2c as a data engineer this is a common issue -- we often embed SQL code inside other languages like Python.  Given that I believe vim is the last editor we would ever need, seems like there would be a solution somewhere...

Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/2601403/4748017

@ScottEdwards2000 there are plenty of solutions; I linked one

thanks, @d-ben-knoble !  If we have to set start and end criteria, I'm guessing I could put a comment at the beginning and end of my SQL queries embedded in Python (and is there a way to set the "default" syntax highlighting to be Python so I don't have to demarcate that as well? [would just automatically go back to Python after end of SQL]).  Anyway, I'm probably getting ahead of myself - I don't even have syntax highlighting set up in vim yet - still mastering the basics!  thanks again!
